# ZFS pools and filesystems

Tags: solaris, zfs

is there any way to understand (using zfs and zpool commads) to whcih pool is a ZFS filesystem assigned?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The part before the first slash in a ZFS filesystem's name is the name of the zpool:

```
$ zfs list
NAME                   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
logstorage            2.00T   585G  27.9K  none
logstorage/archive    1.99T   585G  1.99T  /usr/local/var/log/archive
logstorage/current    5.87G   585G  5.87G  /usr/local/var/log/current
logstorage/snmptraps  76.7M   585G  76.7M  /usr/local/var/log/snmptraps
logstorage/test       5.71G   585G  5.71G  /usr/local/var/log/syslog-test

$ zpool list
NAME         SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
logstorage  3.08T  2.34T   751G    76%  ONLINE  -
```

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

`zfs list` shows you the list like

**pool**/path     used  avail  refer  mounpoint

so the pool part is what you need.